# BOOL Property is returning wrong BOOL result

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, boolean, lldb

A `BOOL` property is returning `NO` despite its backing iVar says it is  `Yes`.

### The Problem

I have a class `PFIBinaryPointView` with a `BOOL` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isGlowing) BOOL glowing;
```

I am testing another class `sut` with Kiwi. Part of this class is a method `numberToDisplay:` to set or unset the `glowing` property.

```
context(@"when numberToDisplay is called", ^{
    __block PFIBinaryPointView *point;
    it(@"should activate the correct points for the number 1", ^{
        [sut numberToDisplay:1];
        point = [sut.binaryPoints objectAtIndex:0];
        [[theValue([point isGlowing]) should] equal:theValue(YES)];
    });
});
```

But the `isGlowing` always returns a `NO` despite its baking iVar says it is (as it should be) `YES`

[image]

### What I Have Tried:

- At first i thought it was a Kiwi problem but then I testet to insert a helper BOOL
  `BOOL test = point.isGlowing;` But  `test` was `NO` all the time too.
- I tried logging it with a NSLog statement to see if there is any discrepancy  -> always `No` or 0.
- I double checked the `PFIBinaryPointView` class for any implicit declaration of an iVar. But I use the default getter and setter and there is no `@synthesize` anywhere too.
- I tried to rename the property. Befor it was called `isActive`.
- I did a clean for the hole project.
- I restarted Xcode several times.

So if anyone could explain me this strange behavior please do so or better tell me how to convince the property to return the correct result.

Comment: Another success story in the journals of Apples "helpful" auto-generated-synthesise functionality.  When will people realise that being explicit might cost keystrokes but at least they know what is going on...

Comment: just remove the `getter=isGlowing` and I expect it will work. Or, you can add `@synthesize glowing = _glowing` to your @implementation. (Personally, I never use _getter=_, I don't see the point)

Comment: @trojanfoe, can you actually explain the problem? Pfitz, can you reproduce the problem on a smaller, self-contained piece of code?

Comment: Have you tried to print the value if the instance variable _glowing in the debugger console or with NSLog? Sometimes the debugger variables view just displays wrong data.

Comment: is the method isGlowing actually implemented? maybe that will help

Comment: A `BOOL` can have a value this is not 0 and not 1, for example: 0x10. That has the undesired effect, that despite two BOOLs are not `NO`, the may not be equal! This is a problem in the current Objective-C language, lacking a boolean  "**Type**".

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, see the screenshot. The backing variable is `YES`, the value returned by the accessor is `NO`. I don’t think you can arrive at this situation by storing some non-boolean integer in a `BOOL` variable.

Comment: @zoul There are often issues in Xcode regarding the variable pane. The (lldb)console is probably more accurate. I would try `$ (lldb)  p (int) point.isGlowing`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try frame variable point._glowing and see what it reports?

If it lies to you, then it’s time for a bug report

If it says the right thing, try right clicking on the _glowing iVar, and editing its summary. I suspect a “YES” to show up in the resulting window.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in some 3rd party code.  Looks like the bool wasn't initialized anywhere and xcode assumes it's true when it's actually auto-initialized to false!  (Anyway.. initializing the bool fixed my problem).